# SharePoint search box not encoding special characters

Tags: search, sharepoint, spfx

We have a modern SharePoint site. We are using pnp search results webpart for displaying search results in a page. In search settings we are using this customized search results page instead of using out of box search.aspx page

Issue:

---

When we are entering some special characters like "C++" keyword in search box, these characters are not encoded and hence results are not coming properly.
It is supposed to come like

/Search.aspx?q=C%2B%2B

But it is coming as

/CustomReults.aspx?q=C++

I presume if we can get the query like below, it will work.  But how to get that. Need help badly..

/CustomReults.aspx?q=C%2B%2B

Comment: hi @dhanu, i'm facing the same issue. do you found any workaround